# sending emails using windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

**SCENARIO:** I want to send emails to all the followers of my website as soon as a new article is submitted.

**PROBLEM:** I want to send the emails asynchronously using threading or a windows service. I am not sure about windows service as I am using a shared hosting. But my real concern is that I want to send out the emails only when traffic is low in my site. How do I go about this? Ho do I check if traffic is low or not?

Comment: Why not use RSS and recommend your users to use some RSS->Email service?

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo My client wants to use email service...any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to avoid any form of traffic testing as this is non-trivial and to use an external service to manage newsletters.

There are third-party services (such as for example Cakemail) who will maintain lists of subscribers which you can manage through an API.

Your site could trigger a mass mailing from one of these services when you publish a new article without incurring a performance penalty on your hosting provider's kit.

Comment: actually i am not sending emails to every user of the site rather to the followers of the user who is submitting the article..so i kinda need the windows services way...any idea?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to consult your analytics data (Google Analytics or StatCounter or whatever is your poison) and you'll soon see a general trend when your website is the most quiet.

Configure your web service to only send out emails at that time.  You could put that configuration value in its `config` file but maybe store it in a database so it's easier to modify?

That way you can use the webservice to send your emails out automatically and have the power to configure it to run when your website has fewest visitors - saves load testing and monitoring :)

If you did want to monitor CPU/Memory use then I believe there is a lot available in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace for you ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx)), including access to all the stuff in PerfMon.

I hope that might help :) Good luck.